# Redirect Page based on dropdown information in ASp.NET mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a dropdown control have two type of values 'Contractor' and 'Full time', based on the dropdown selection relevant controls will be displayed.

Now when i click on the submit button i have to redirect to different action method (i.e) when 'Contractor' is selected it should redirect to AddContractor() else it should redirect to Full time along with the filled information.

How to implement it using single Html.Beginform()

Comment: You cant use `Html.Beginform()` (its html is generated on the server before its sent to the view, so it could only ever contain the initial value). You need to post back the value of the selected option. Show your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you can do:

On View:

```
    @{
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Contractor", Value = "0" });

    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Full time", Value = "1" });
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Go", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("Example", items)

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}

<p>Value selected: @ViewBag.Info</p>
```

On Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Go(int example)
    {
        if (example != null)
        {
            if (example == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AddContractor", new { info = example});
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Other", new {info = example});
            }
        }
        return View("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult AddContractor(int info)
    {
        ViewBag.Info = info;
        return View("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult Other(int info)
    {
        ViewBag.Info = info;
        return View("Index");
    }
```

You can use another view and other info for your project. I just code example to redirect action and model info.

Hope can help you :)